# Is it possible to define a default_scope in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, scope, mongoose

In Rails there is `default_scope` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope) which allows specifying a default set of rules that are applied, when querying models from database. Is there a way to do the same thing in Mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a thing exists, but you could create your own version of, for instance, `find`:

```
yourSchema.static('myFind', function() {
  var query = arguments[0];
  ...augment your query here...
  return this.find.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

And instead of `Model.find()`, you use `Model.myFind()`.